# Converting EGLImageKHR to greyscale

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm creating an EGLImageKHR image like this :

```
EGLImageKHR image = eglCreateImageKHR(mEGLDisplay, EGL_NO_CONTEXT,
                    EGL_NATIVE_BUFFER_ANDROID, buffer, NULL);
```

The `image`, as I think, will be in RGB color space. Is there anyway to get an image with greyscale color space out of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eglCreateImageKHR doesn't do any color conversion. It will just wrap the `buffer` you pass into it so your `image` will have the same format as what that `buffer` was allocated with.

Comment: So, is there any way to convert the image or the buffer to greyscale image at some point before or later somehow ?

Comment: You won't be able to convert the image itself without it being detached (or orphaned) from the eglImage. Assuming you are using this image in OpenGL ES 2.0 or later you can do the conversion in the fragment shader.